# APT package is broken due to a competing one

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04

I've recently updated my ubuntu server on do from 16.04 to 18.04 and then from 18.04 to 20.04. I managed to make it to 20.04, but things were messed up during the upgrade. Now according to my research and what people tell, there are probably broken packages or remnant files which causes issues. Two plugins on my wp site says curl is not installed, this is where I start to dig this issue.

output of `dpkg -l 'php*'`

```
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name               Version                                      Architectur>
+++-==================-============================================-===========>
ii  php                2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4        all        >
un  php-amqp           <none>                                       <none>     >
ii  php-apcu           5.1.19+4.0.11-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 amd64      >
ii  php-apcu-bc        1.0.5-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1         amd64      >
un  php-ast            <none>                                       <none>     >
ii  php-bz2            2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4        all        >
un  php-calendar       <none>                                       <none>     >
un  php-cli            <none>                                       <none>     >
ii  php-common         2:79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4            all        >
un  php-crypt-gpg      <none>                                       <none>     >
un  php-ctype          <none>                                       <none>     >
un  php-curl           <none>                                       <none>     >
un  php-dom            <none>                                       <none>     >
un  php-exif           <none>                                       <none>     >
un  php-ffi            <none>                                       <none>     >
un  php-fileinfo       <none>                                       <none>     >
un  php-fpm            <none>                                       <none>     >
un  php-ftp            <none>                                       <none>     >
```

output of `dpkg -l '*curl*' | grep ^ii`

```
ii libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2 amd64 easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
ii libcurl4:amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2 amd64 easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)
ii python3-pycurl 7.43.0.2-1ubuntu5 amd64 Python bindings to libcurl (Python 3)
```

Output of `apt-cache policy php7.4-curl`

```
php7.4-curl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4
  Version table:
     7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 500
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     7.4.3-4ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

output of `apt list --installed php*`

```
php-apcu-bc/now 1.0.5-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php-apcu/now 5.1.19+4.0.11-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 amd64 [installed,local]
php-bz2/now 2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 all [installed,local]
php-common/now 2:79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 all [installed,local]
php-gd/now 2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 all [installed,local]
php-gmp/now 2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 all [installed,local]
php-json/now 2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 all [installed,local]
php-mbstring/now 2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 all [installed,local]
php-mysql/now 2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 all [installed,local]
php-pspell/now 2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 all [installed,local]
php-recode/now 1:7.2+60ubuntu1 all [installed,local]
php-soap/now 2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 all [installed,local]
php-tidy/now 2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 all [installed,local]
php-xml/now 2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 all [installed,local]
php-xmlrpc/now 2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 all [installed,local]
php-zip/now 2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 all [installed,local]
php5.6-apcu/now 5.1.19+4.0.11-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-apcu-bc/now 1.0.5-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-apcu/now 5.1.19+4.0.11-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-bz2/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-cli/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-common/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-gd/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-gmp/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-json/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-mbstring/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-mysql/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-opcache/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-pspell/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-readline/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-soap/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-xml/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-xmlrpc/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0-zip/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.0/now 7.0.33-37+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all [installed,local]
php7.1-apcu-bc/now 1.0.5-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.1-apcu/now 5.1.19+4.0.11-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.2-apcu-bc/now 1.0.5-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.2-apcu/now 5.1.19+4.0.11-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.2-common/now 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.7 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.2-recode/now 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.7 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3-apcu-bc/now 1.0.5-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3-apcu/now 5.1.19+4.0.11-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3-cli/now 7.3.24-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3-common/now 7.3.24-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3-fpm/now 7.3.24-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3-gd/now 7.3.24-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3-json/now 7.3.24-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3-mbstring/now 7.3.24-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3-mysql/now 7.3.24-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3-opcache/now 7.3.24-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3-readline/now 7.3.24-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3-xml/now 7.3.24-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3-xmlrpc/now 7.3.24-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3-zip/now 7.3.24-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.3/now 7.3.24-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all [installed,local]
php7.4-apcu-bc/now 1.0.5-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-apcu/now 5.1.19+4.0.11-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-bz2/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-cli/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-common/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-fpm/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-gd/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-gmp/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-json/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-mbstring/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-mysql/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-opcache/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-pspell/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-readline/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-soap/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-tidy/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-xml/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-xmlrpc/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4-zip/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php7.4/now 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all [installed,local]
php8.0-apcu/now 5.1.19+4.0.11-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 amd64 [installed,local]
php/now 2:7.4+79+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 all [installed,local]
```

Answer (score 0):

> @rem3on Judging by one of your comments to the question, there's an
> older version of php7.4-common still installed. To install php-curl,
> you need to also install php7.4-curl. That in turn depends on
> php7.4-common. In Ubuntu 20.04, php7.4-common corresponds to
> 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4. But a "competing" php7.4-common is already installed, being 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1. This looks
> like PHP 7.4 for Ubuntu 16.04. – Henning Kockerbeck 14 hours ago

Checking out Henning Kockerbeck's answer again in another post, I ran sudo apt-get purge php7.4-common and then ''sudo apt install php php-cli php-fpm php-json php-common php-mysql php-zip php-gd php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath'' And, the problem has been solved, I don't get curl is missing error now. Though this problem is solved I have to make sure that there is no mess in the server, what can I do right now to make sure everything is ok. Also there might be more problem rather than curl is missing, could you help me with that?